# Add new IP to Ubuntu through VMware fusion for node.js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vmware

I'm have a vm of Ubuntu that's running Apache on port 80.  I'm also setting up a node.js server on the same VM (this is just development) and want to also use port 80.  From what I understand by using node http-proxy, I can accomplish this.  I'll just need a new IP for the node instance.

How do I create a new IP on the VM?

Thank you!

Comment: i think this is better suited on http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Although I am not sure your approach is correct, you just need to create additional network interface on your VM and configure it, to obtain second IP.

Answer (score 0):

On VMWare you could set the Network Connection to Bridged under Network Adapter settings.